# swift LaunchScreen won't show

Tags: swift, storyboard, xcode11, launch-screen

My app used assets to show Launch Screen so I've decided to move to a Storyboard, here is the one I've created:

[image]

and here the config of the project

[image]

But I keep having black screen

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted the storyboard and recreated one and it works now